# How to insert a new row into table where values are variables?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to `INSERT` a new row into table using variables, like this-

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
if($name && $surname && $email && $password){
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $db = '_erica';
    $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    };

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO login(id, name, surname, email, sex, password) VALUES (Null,$name,$surname,$email,$gender,$password)';

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    }else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

}else{
    die('All fields requiret!');
};
```

But it does not work, I have tried to add quotes around variables like this

```
 $sql = 'INSERT INTO login(id, name, surname, email, sex, password) VALUES(Null,"$name","$surname","$email","$gender","$password")';
```

still nothing... what could I do?

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: If the ID is an auto-increment field you should just omit it

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO login(id, name, surname, email, sex, password) VALUES(NULL,"'.$name.'","'.$surname.'","'.$email.'","'.$gender.'","'.$password.'")';
```

Or (use double quotes outside instead of single quotes)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO login(id, name, surname, email, sex, password) VALUES(NULL,$name,$surname,$email,$gender,$password)";
```

Comment: and if id is auto increment than?

Comment: Id has to be primary key, auto increment. on inserting NULL it will auto increment the value.

Comment: auto increament not NULL ???

Comment: no need to use NULL brother.

Comment: It has to be set in the database. The id field as AUTO_INCREMENT.

Answer (score 1):

Use this. Just change single quotes with double quotes

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO login(id, name, surname, email, sex, password) VALUES (Null,$name,$surname,$email,$gender,$password)";
```

Comment: and if id is auto increment than?

Comment: Remove `id` and `NULL`

`$sql = "INSERT INTO login(name, surname, email, sex, password) VALUES ($name,$surname,$email,$gender,$password)";`

Comment: than my vote for you ....

Comment: Thanks! Just set id as auto increment in DB